# How to get values from xml string with duplicate nodes names in php and show it?

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have a xml string which looks like this,

```
 <xml>
   <type>name</type>
     <name>
        <namedata>abc</namedata>
        <namedata>efg</namedata>
        <namedata>ijk</namedata>
     </name>
 <xml>
```

*REQUIREMENT:*
I need to parse the xml to php and show it in a table such that it will display like this

```
   type   namedata   namedata   namedata
   name      abc        efg        ijk
```

I tried doing this using foreach but only could get the first value of namedata. Here is what i have done so far :

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr><td>type'</td></tr>'.$xml->type.'</td><tr>';
  foreach($xml->name as $row){
     echo'<td>'.$row->namedata.'</td>';
    }
   echo'</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there are multiple namdata nodes you can load them as an array like so:

```
foreach($xml->name->namedata as $row){
    echo'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
}
```

as for this "Requirement". The easiest way i found was something like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><td>type</td>';
for($x=0;$x<count($xml->name->namedata);$x++){
    echo '<td>namedata</td>';
}
echo '</tr><tr><td>'.$xml->type.'</td>';
foreach($xml->name->namedata as $row){
    echo'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
}
echo'</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($response);
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>type</td></tr>'.$xml->type.'</td></tr>';
  foreach($xml->name->namedata as $row){
     echo '<td>'.$row.'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr></table>';
```